# How to prevent a user to access other user data using user id?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I made a link using

```
Route::get('/admin/edit/user/{user_id}', [UserController::class, 'editUser'])->name('edit.user');
```

That is why when a user click on edit he see https://0608sns.org/admin/edit/user/1789
and he can edit his profile but if that user put another id like 1790 he can use that user profile.
So, How can i prevent it?

Comment: this is what Authorization is for

Comment: Typically, you'd have a separate Route, `/profile` (or similar), which references the currently Authenticated User. Anyone can navigate to `/profile` and see and edit their own profile (assuming someone is logged in, Middleware would handle that), and you'd then have a separate Route `/user/{user}/edit` (or similar), which only allowed Users can access (i.e. Admins).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`Policies`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#creating-policies) to allow an entity to do something or not.

In your example, you should create a Policy called `UserPolicy` with `php artisan make:policy UserPolicy`, and the contents of it should be:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Policies;
 
use App\Models\User;
 
class UserPolicy
{
    public function update(User $user, User $userToEdit): bool
    {
        return $user->id === $userToEdit->id;
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, you should have something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, int $user_id): RedirectResponse
{
    $userToEdit = User::findOrFail($user_id);

    $this->authorize('update', $userToEdit);

    // Do whatever you need to

    return redirect('/');
}
```

I may be missing something, this is from the top of my head, so try it out and let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your suggestion is working, when i use it user can not edit others data. but how can i prevent another user url by id?

Comment: @H.M.Mohiuddin I did not understand your question. Could you add an example or edit your question with the issue? If this is working and that's it, please mark this answer as the solution

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need a simple `Gate` [Policies also great]
But for simple authorizations like this, we prefer Gates.
Go over here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#writing-gates